# Converting case of all values in all fields of table using ArcPy & Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Does anyone know how to use the .upper() in a stand alone python script so it can be used to change all characters in a table into UPPER case?  I don't want to use the field calculator since I have multiple tables, etc...

I currently am using a cursor to correct mistakes in my tables, but can't figure out the correct syntax to use it to convert all the strings to UPPER case!

---

The above question would apply equally well when the change of case desired is to lower or title.

Comment: [How to change a string into uppercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257094/how-to-change-a-string-into-uppercase)

Comment: I think the user is asking how to convert every field in a table to upper case in one move. No?

Comment: Correct.  So, something similar to the VB code in the field calculator - UCase(fieldname)...but I want to do it to the whole table using an update cursor...I can't figure out what to put before the .upper()...I've listed my fields, and now want to write something like - if row[0] is (something), then upper case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following example shows how to integrate the built-in python method `.upper()` with the arcpy update cursor.  This example first tests if a field is of type String then checks each row within that string for lowercase values.  If there are lower case values, the row is updated with all upper case.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\temp\test.gdb\yourFC'

desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
fields = desc.fields

for field in fields:
    if field.Type == "String":
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, str(field.name)) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0] == None:  # Check for "<Null>"
                    continue
                else:
                    any(x.islower() for x in row[0]) == True
                    row[0] = row[0].upper()
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Aaron,thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! The only thing I noticed is that NULL values are not iterable, so I ran a quick script to get these blank. Out of curiosity, do you know how to jump over those NULL values in this script?

Comment: No problem, I have updated the script with logic to check for <Null>.

Comment: Really impressive. I've learned a lot in this little script. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `.upper()` in python:

```
data = "lower case data"
upper_case_data = data.upper()
print upper_case_data
```

it can also be used directly with a string

```
print "lower case data".upper()
```

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.  Do you know how I would use this with a search cursor?  I'm going through each field in my table and if there are any lower case characters, I want them to change to upper case.

Comment: @Dane What database system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Arcmap 10.1 and writing my code in PythonWin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example:

```
fc = "whatever"
fields = ("Name", "Addy", "Stuff")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[0].upper()
        row[1] = row[1].upper()
        row[2] = row[2].upper()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

And here's the ArcGIS manual for the [da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've realized that the issue I'm having is having the cursor hit each field. I don't want to have to list all the field names...The manual for the da.UpdateCursor says to use (*) if you want all field names to be used, but I can never get that to work...seeing you reinforce the row[0] = row[0].upper() has definately helped...I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough street credit!

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but different to above:

```
import arcpy
fc = "YOUR FC"
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.Type == "String"]

cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in cur:
    for field in fields:
        try:
            row.setValue(field) = row.getValue(field).upper()
        except:
            pass
    row.updateCursor(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, Darryl!  Any particular reason you didn't use arcpy.da.UpdateCursor?  I'm at home and don't have my data, but I'm assuming that the "pass" would prevent the NULL iterable error...nice.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I am still running 10.0 - so don't have the arcpy.da.UpdateCursor available yet.  I know that this is faster - so that change will improve you efficiency.  Also, I would imagine that running through the cursor 1 time will be faster than running through it 1 time for each field as the accepted answer shows.  Hope it works for you!