# Converting text to proper case using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

I am working on a set of data that has over 40,000 records on ArcGIS and I want to use a Proper Case for several fields/columns on the table.

Is there a Python Script that can help me automate this process as I desire to save time while working on this records?

Comment: ESRI Technical Article on the subject: http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38592

Comment: Does the accepted answer to this question not answer yours? [Converting case of all values in all fields of table using ArcPy & Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92673/converting-case-of-all-values-in-all-fields-of-table-using-arcpy-python)  Just use **.title()** in place of **.upper()**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean a capital letter at the start of each word you can use python's [title method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_title.htm)

```
str.title()
```

where str is your input field.

You can use this in field calculator on all records

Comment: Thanks so much for this. But like I said I would like to work on multiple fields/columns at the same time.

Comment: You cant run the field calculator in all columns at the same time. Do you have many columns? If not you're probably best just repeating it, but if there are too many you could write a python script and an update cursor http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000